# Faraday vs HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[Faraday](https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday) is the ruby HTTP client library of choice. Why is it preferable to use it over [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty)?

Some things that I would like compared are:

- Performance
- Architecture
- Ease of use
- Features existing in Faraday that isn't in HTTParty (or vice versa)
- Anything else that makes Faraday the library of choice.

Comment: I fail to see the foundation of your statement that faraday is the library of choice - I've hear a lot about HTTParty, and almost nothing about Faraday...

Answer (score 25):

They differ in many aspects, but here's the essence IMHO:

HTTParty:
- Uses net/http
- Some magic (e.g. parse JSON responses)

Faraday:
- A wrapper around most of the http libraries out there (excon, typhoeus, net-http-persistent, etc.)
- Allows to craft the request and response middleware that suits your specific needs.

I personally prefer Faraday, as it allows me to switch to any http library, and because it allows very fine-grain control over the request and response.

Comment: Could you go into detail about the fine-grained request/response control?

Comment: You can register some middleware that modifies the request and/or response. It works in a similar way to rack, so you're in complete control of the body and headers that go both ways.

Answer (score 7):

I was at the point of having to make the same decision yesterday. However, I just need a library that can do simple http requests, nothing fancy... I was however looking for something that is easier to use than *Net::HTTP*.

For my purposes, both libraries seemed equally well suited, so I decided to go with the one introducing less overhead. Since I also use the *twitter* gem in this project, I went with *faraday* since the *twitter* gem already depends on it and I get it included in my project for "free"...