# Making simultaneous http requests in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

I'm trying to download a number of RSS feeds (50k), I'm estimating at the current speed it's going to take ~18-hours.  Is there any way to speed this up by doing two at once?  Three at once?

```
response = HTTParty.get(uri_encoded_term)
```

Comment: Can you use sup-processes?

Comment: Look at [Ruby threads](http://www.sitepoint.com/threads-ruby/) perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [Typhoeus: A High Speed, Parallel HTTP Library for Ruby](http://www.rubyinside.com/typhoeus-a-high-speed-parallel-http-library-for-ruby-1767.html)

See also: 
  - [Faraday vs HTTParty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841960/faraday-vs-httparty)

Answer (score 1):

You could use many threads to download your resources, keep in mind you are bounded by your Internet connection.

Concept:

```
# Our list of threads
threads = []

# Iterate over all our urls
urls.each do |url|
  threads << Thread.new do
    response = HTTParty.get(uri_encoded_term)
    # Do fancy stuff with your response, remember thread safety!
  end
end

# Wait for all threads
threads.each &:join
```

I just hope you do all this in your backend, and not during the request cycle.